# Convert stream of List<Object> to stream of all Objects in the List

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-stream

The following lambda expressions take the values of a HashMap, gets a List of Objects in its ArrayList, adds all such Objects to another ArrayList, and then prints each attribute if a condition is met.

This works, but I am a bit frustrated I couldn't figure out how to do this in one step, as in, not using two lambda expressions.

```
Map<Integer, Person> people = new HashMap<Integer, Person>();
...
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

people.values().stream()
    .map(p->p.getObjects())
    .forEach(p->objects.addAll(p)); //note: can be multiple
objects.stream()
    .filter(p->p.getClass().toString().contains("Keyword"))
    .forEach(p->System.out.println(p.display()));
```

So is there a way I can go from line 2 to line 5 directly, which would in effect convert a stream of List of Objects to a stream of all of the Objects themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge your operations to a single stream pipeline as

```
List<Pet> cats = people.values().stream()
        .flatMap(p -> p.getPets().stream())
        .filter(p -> p.getClass().toString().contains("Cat")) // or Cat.class::isInstance
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and then perform operations on them as in your code such as

```
cats.forEach(cat -> System.out.println(cat.getName()));
```

An overall transformation of your code would look like:

```
Map<Integer, Person> people = ...;
people.values().stream()
        .flatMap(p -> p.getPets().stream())
        .filter(p -> p.getClass().toString().contains("Cat"))
        .forEach(cat -> System.out.println(cat.getName()));
```

Comment: At the end, you can do `.map(Pet::getName).forEach(System.out::println)`